# Select-Option returns every option not just selected option

Tags: angular, html-select

I've created a select list with options, and when an option is selected I want to be able to read what the option that was selected was.
When I try read the option it returns the full list of every option that was available to choose.

The options are created from an array and displayed using `*ngFor`.

**.component.html**:

```
<form action="">
    <select id ="fruitSelect" (change)="fruity()" name="fruitSelect" autofocus >
      <option>Enter/Select Fruit</option>
      <option  *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" value="fruit">{{fruit}}</option>
    </select>
  </form>
```

**.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  fruits: any = ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana', 'Orange']

  fruity() {
    var e = document.getElementById("fruitSelect")
    console.log(e.textContent)
  }
}
```

View example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-she3aq)

Currently, this returns `Enter/Select FruitApplePearBananaOrange`, I want just `Orange` for example.

How do I return just the selected option?
Also, I do not want to have a submit button, I want the function to run when the option changes hence the use of `(change)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `[(ngModel)]="selectedFruit" (change)="fruity($event)"` or `(change)="fruity($event.target.value)"`

Try this:

```
<select id ="fruitSelect" (change)="fruity($event)" name="fruitSelect" autofocus [(ngModel)]="selectedFruit">
  <option>Enter/Select Fruit</option>
  <option  *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [value]="fruit">{{fruit}}</option>
</select>
```

TS:

```
 fruity(selectedValue) {      
    console.log(selectedValue)
  }
```